# how to delete default values in text field using selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-rc

I want to delete a default value of a textbox to enter the new value, but I am not getting how to do that.

I was thinking to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>Delete</kbd> but I'm not sure how to do this.

I even used WebDriver's command `driver.findElement("locator").clear();`.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you get an Exception, or nothing happened, or...?

Comment: Also, can you write to the element? If you tried `element.sendKeys("bla")`, would the text append itself to the existing one? ... If nothing helps, please show us the HTML code of the element. Something there could be done in a unusual way that breaks things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution from Selenium RC, you can use simply

```
// assuming 'selenium' is a healthy Selenium instance
selenium.type("someLocator", "");
```

Comment: What did it do? What happens when you try to type some text? Is there any exception?

Comment: it neither throws an exception nor do it removes the values, i even tried to overwrite the value with some other value....

Comment: Show us the code of the HTML element. All these things you mention should work.

Comment: @user1374181 Now I'm seriously baffled. Why did I get the accept? Right, it is the correct answer, but it wasn't working in your case, was it?

Comment: ur command worked but was issue with the page, it was acting like a pop up when it wasn't,i changed selectWindow to selectPop and my problem was solved using ur suggestions. so thank u very much.

Answer (score 53):

And was the code helpful? Because the code you are writing should do the thing:

```
driver.findElement("locator").clear();
```

If it does not help, then try this:

```
WebElement toClear = driver.findElement("locator");
toClear.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
toClear.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

maybe you will have to do some convert of the `Keys.CONTROL + "a"` to CharSequence, but the first approach should do the magic

Comment: @user1374181 I don't understand your question - what does it mean "simple JUnit"? These are Selenium WebDriver commands taking advantage of the [Keys enum](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) in Selenium.

Comment: @Slanec : I mean if not possible with selenium2 can it be used with junit using RC.

Comment: so is it possible with selenium1?

Comment: It is causing error " `error: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated ` "
when I am using ` Global.driver.FindElement(rangeFrom).Clear(); `. Unfortunately this works when debug code it works. May be it needs additional wait times. @PavelJanicek

Answer (score 4):

For page object model -

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//foo")
   public WebElement textBox;
```

now in your function

```
 public void clearExistingText(String newText){
    textBox.clear();
    textBox.sendKeys(newText);
  }
```

for general selenium architecture -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//yourxpath")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//yourxpath")).sendKeys("newText");
```

Comment: This is not working, it delete the text at the beginning of the Edit text value

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below. It selects the pre-existing value in the field and overwrites it with the new value.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*enter your xpath here*")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"),*enter the new value here*);
```

Answer (score 2):

`driver.findElement(locator).clear()` - This command will work in all cases

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Java, v3.14.  It does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`clear()` didn't work for me. But this did:

```
input.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.chord("a")); //select all text in textbox
input.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE); //delete it
input.sendKeys("new text"); //enter new text
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function will delete the input character one by one till the input field is empty using PromiseWhile

```
driver.clearKeys = function(element, value){
  return element.getAttribute('value').then(function(val) {
    if (val.length > 0) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var len;
        len = val.length;
        return promiseWhile(function() { 
          return 0 < len;
        }, function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            len--;
            return element.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.BACK_SPACE).then(function()              {
              return resolve(true);
            });
          });
        }).then(function() {
          return resolve(true);
        });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(yourElement).clear();
driver.findElement(yourelement).sendKeys("");
```

Comment: In Java, I'm seeing that `clear()` does nothing

Answer (score 0):

.clear() can be used to clear the text

```
  (locator).clear();
```

using clear with the locator deletes all the value in that exact locator.

Answer (score 0):

In software testing services this can be achieved by many ways some of the options are displayed above remaining are as follow.

- Using java script

driver.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('element').setAttribute('value', 'abc')");

Using action class
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.click(driver.findElement(element)   .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).build().perform());

Answer (score 0):

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
ak = driver.find_element_by_id('blogname')
actions.move_to_element(ak)
actions.click()
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_down(Keys.DELETE)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.